# C++ For Loop with multiple independent arguments

Tags: c++, for-loop

is there a way in C++ to write something like

```
    for(int a1=0; a1<n;a1++)
    { 
        for (int a2 = 0; a2 < m; a2++)
        {
          some stuff
        }
        
    }
```

in a single loop. I already saw stuff like

```
for(int i =0, int j=0; i<n && j<m; i++,j++)
```

but I want the increments to be independent and not synchronous.

Comment: This is what nested for loop are for.

Comment: What do you mean by independency? Isn't a nested for loop enough?

Comment: **Arguments** are passed in functions and generally used for them. I don't know what do you exactly meant by - *multiple independent arguments*.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know that nested loops are a thing, but I need to write lots of them and wanted to know if there was a faster way.

Comment: Depends on exactly what you are doing.  Maybe you should either edit this question and how ask how to simplify/reduce you code that uses the nested for loops, or ask a new question doing the same thing.

Comment: @Michele "wanted to know if there was a faster way" - Define "faster", please. Do you mean "faster to type", "faster to read" or "will execute faster"? For the last, I think you'll find that your compilers optimizer is more than capable of generating the same optimal code regardless of whether you write one loop or two nested ones..

Comment: Start with the simplest way to describe the behaviour you want. Worry about fast if testing finds you really do need fast. [Premature optimization and all that...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way you can do it with range-v3:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;

for (auto [a1, a2] : rv::cartesian_product(rv::iota(0, n), rv::iota(0, m)))
  // use a1 and a2
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/F_BCQk).

You can extend this to deeper levels of nesting by adding more arguments to `rv::cartesian_product`.

Comment: I have colleagues who swear by this method. I can see where they come from. But whenever we have new interns, we waste about a week training them on range-v3, whereas nested loops seem universally understood.

Comment: @Jeffrey That's fair. I'm not saying this style is appropriate to teach everywhere. But is it possible that the interns have already spent some time getting familiar with loops? I actually find this easier to teach to beginners. Anyway, I'm just sharing an alternative :)

Comment: Yeah, nice to point it out. But one last point :-). It's also much slower: https://godbolt.org/z/ZUFxGq

Comment: @Jeffrey Hmm, I doubt it. No point measuring without [optimizations](https://godbolt.org/z/4E_GbT) enabled anyway :)

Comment: Looking at the generated code, even when optimized this method is more complicated - including some assert checks and an exception - so I don't see any benefit here: the code is less readable to anybody not very familiar with what it is doiing, and the performance lags.

Comment: I'm no performance expert, but there seem to be no fundamental reasons why this version should be slower than the other. In practice, there may be, but fwiw I've never had an issue with this. It does compile slower for sure. Readability is subjective, and I'm only stating my preference.

Comment: I stand corrected

Answer (score 0):

The "nested loops" way is the correct way to do it.

If you really want cryptic code, you can try:

```
for(int i =0; i < n*m; i++)
{ 
    int a1 = i % n;
    int a2 = i / n;
     
    // some stuff        
}
```

but it's possible your colleagues will end up hating you.